# [c#]таймер C#. как сократить потребление ресурсов ЦП

Tags: c#, winforms, cmd

Есть некий код, в котором по таймеру запускается процесс cmd. В cmd передается команда "показать состояние размещённой сети" (netsh wlan show hostednetwork). Результат заносится в переменную log1 Затем через некоторую паузу Task.Delay вызывается цикл foreach поиска mac адреса через регулярное выражение

```
Regex.IsMatch(podstroka, "..:..:..:..:..:..")
```

вот часть кода

```
public async void GetClients()
    {
        RegistryKey RegKeysMac = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\MyFI\DB");

        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Process proc = Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                StandardOutputEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("CP866"),
                FileName = "PowerShell",
                Arguments = "& 'cmd' '/c chcp 866 & netsh wlan show hostednetwork'", //powershell используется здесь вместо cmd из-за проблем с кодировкой на win7 
                UseShellExecute = false,
                CreateNoWindow = true,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true

            });
            try
            {
                string[] log1 = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd().ToString().Remove(0, 465).Split();
                foreach (string podstroka in log1)
                {
                    if (Regex.IsMatch(podstroka, "..:..:..:..:..:.."))
                    {
                        MAClist.Items.Add(podstroka);
                    }


                }
                foreach (string item in MAClist.Items) //Поиск присвоенных имен устройств по MAC в базе программы
                {
                    foreach (string Keyname in RegKeysMac.GetValueNames())
                    {

                        if (item.Contains(Keyname))
                        {
                            string value = RegKeysMac.GetValue(Keyname).ToString();
                            DeviceNameList.Items.Add(value);
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
            catch
            {
            }

        });

        ClientsNumber.Text = MAClist.Items.Count.ToString();

    }
```

Данный цикл повторяется примерно каждые 10 секунд (время задается пользователем). Вопрос в том, как сократить потребление ресурсов? Есть версия, чтобы запускать cmd или powershell только 1 раз и по очереди передовать команды, делать паузу, потом опять передать команду. Но не понятно, как сделать так, чтобы таймер передавал команды именно в нужный процесс.

```
cls
netsh wlan show drivers
Task.Delay(1000)
```

Может есть другой способ? Пробовал делать так

```
  public void GetClienst() //это тестовый блок, чтобы сократить потребление ресурсов
        {
            richTextBox1.Text = "";
            cmdProc.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "cls");

            cmdProc.Start();
            cmdProc.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
            {
                StandardErrorEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("CP866"),
                FileName = "cmd",
                Arguments = "/c netsh wlan show hostednetwork",
                UseShellExecute = false,
                CreateNoWindow = true,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true

            };

            cmdProc.Start();

            cmdProc.WaitForExit();
            richTextBox1.Text = cmdProc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

        }
```

но в итоге запускается новый экземпляр cmd

второй таймер выводит уведомления о контретно подключенном / отключенном устр-ве

```
private void notificationsTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string deviceCount = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(@"Software\MyFI\Settings").GetValue("ClientsCount", "0").ToString();
        notifyIcon1.Text = $"MyFI\nПодключенных устр-в: {ClientsNumber.Text}";

        if (ClientsNumber.Text != deviceCount)
        {
            if (Convert.ToInt32(ClientsNumber.Text) > Convert.ToInt32(deviceCount))
            {
                try
                {
                    foreach (string item in DeviceNameList.Items)
                    {
                        if (!DevNames.Contains(item))
                        {

                            DevNames.Add(item);
                            Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(@"Software\MyFI\Settings").SetValue("ClientsCount", ClientsNumber.Text);
                            notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(3, $"Новое подключение ({item})", $"Подключенных устройств {ClientsNumber.Text}", ToolTipIcon.Info);
                            return;
                        }

                    }
                }
                catch { }
                Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(@"Software\MyFI\Settings").SetValue("ClientsCount", ClientsNumber.Text);
                notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(3, "Новое подключение (UnknownDevice)", $"Подключенных устройств {ClientsNumber.Text}", ToolTipIcon.Info);
            }
            else if (Convert.ToInt32(ClientsNumber.Text) < Convert.ToInt32(deviceCount))
            {
                try
                {
                    foreach (string Device in DevNames)
                    {

                        if (!DeviceNameList.Items.Contains(Device))
                        {

                            DevNames.Remove(Device);
                            Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(@"Software\MyFI\Settings").SetValue("ClientsCount", ClientsNumber.Text);
                            notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(3, $"Отключение ({Device})", $"Подключенных устройств {ClientsNumber.Text}", ToolTipIcon.Info);
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch { }
                Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(@"Software\MyFI\Settings").SetValue("ClientsCount", ClientsNumber.Text);
                notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(3, "Отключение (UnknownDevice)", $"Подключенных устройств {ClientsNumber.Text}", ToolTipIcon.Info);
            }

        }
        else
        {
        }

    }
```

Comment: Простите, а зачем вам запускать powershell, через который запускается cmd, через который запускается netsh, странным не кажется такое?

Comment: да, я знаю, что выглядит криво, но напрямую через netsh не выводится ничего или проблема в кодировке

Comment: Ну так вы решите наверно проблему с кодировкой или выводом, а не запускайте 2 доп программы для запуска одной. Также я немного не пойму, зачем вы делаете это асинхронно и как такое вообще может кушать много ресурсов ЦП? Может вы запускаете ваш `GetClients` по сотню раз в секунду?.

Comment: Нет, таймер запускается примерно каждые 12 секунд. Асинхронно я делаю это, чтоб форма не зависала. После 12 секунд нагрузка на цп резко поднимается до 80%, затем всё нормально. Меня это немного напрягает. Неужели так и должно работать?

Comment: Может быть предыдущий поток не успевает закрываться как начинается следующий, хотя в асинхронном методе этого быть не должно

Comment: И в итоге у вас висит бесконечное число тасков, которые ждут закрытие powershell/cmd/netsh?) Вы пробовали закрывать ваш `Process proc` после того, как использовали?

Comment: К сожалению нет.

Comment: Насчёт netsh вы были правы. Сейчас работает так, как нужно

Comment: А как у вас работает таймер? Как вы запускаете задачу?

Comment: По кнопке "Старт" на главной форме. Частота таймера задается пользователем из второй формы "настройки"                                                                                                                     `private void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MAClist.Items.Clear();
            DeviceNameList.Items.Clear();
            GetClients();
            Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(@"Software\MyFI\Settings").SetValue("ClientsCount", ClientsNumber.Text);

        }` извиняюсь за форматирование

Comment: Вы не дали ответ, что за таймер, как он у вас реализован? Вот я например [добился](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1qlg.png) вроде вашей проблемы, путем [такого](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJPCC.png) кода. Как видите у меня есть условно назовем "таймер" (бесконечный цикл), который запускает `async void`, тот в свою очередь запускает ваш код на процесс. Как видите у меня плодится очень много cmd/powershell процессов. Посмотрите на свое приложение через диспетчер, предполагаю, что у вас также.

Comment: Именно так всё и происходит. Алгоритм получения mac адресов был изначально нацелен на работоспособность. Оптимизации никакой нет. Полагаю, что нужно избавиться от асинхронного метода или каждый раз закрывать поток, вызванный этим методом. Забыл уточнить, что у меня 2 таймера. Один как раз тот, что получает MAC-адреса, другой таймер выводит заданные уведомления о конретно подключенном устр-ве. Код я дополнил

Comment: В дотнете несколько разных таймеров. Всегда указывайте, какой именно используете, из какого пространства имён. По сигнатуре можно догадаться, но лучше указать явно.

Comment: `MAClist` - компонент WinForms? Этот код должен падать под отладкой: `MAClist.Items.Add(podstroka);`, т. к. обращение к контролом из другого потока запрещено. Вероятно, в релизе запускаете. Гуглите `Control.Invoke` (на этом сайте множество ответов по теме).

Comment: да, это winForms, `MAClist.Items.Add(podstroka);` работает стабильно, так как выполняется в текущем потоке, если конкретно, то в коде главной формы

Comment: Спасибо вам за советы. Всё было элементарно просто
`proc.Dispose();
proc.Close();`